# Installing Packages does not work; insserv

Tags: apt, 16.04, apache2

I just upgraded my Server from 14.04 to 16.04 but now it seems like **insserv** is causing problems.
I'm trying to install Apache and the following shows up

http://pastebin.com/xb9Yg40A

Is there a way to fix this?

Greetings